# How do I flush DNS cache in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: dns, 22.04

I've already tried `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches` but it ends up showing `sudo: systemd-resolve: command not found`. So, how do I flush the DNS cache in Ubuntu 22?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

22.04 no longer comes with `systemd-resolv` and it is not installable by any packages that I can see in the default repos. An `apt-cache search systemd-resolve` shows that it is in the `resolvconf-admin` package, but when I tried installing that package it did not install `systemd-resolve`.

22.04 comes with `resolvectl` instead.

You can use the following command to flush your caches:

```
sudo resolvectl flush-caches
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It definitely did help me :)